# Why don't we use semi colon after source filename.sql?

Tags: mysql

When importing a sql file to mysql on terminal, why don't we add a semi colon in the end?

like :

```
source file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

semicolon ";" is a sql terminator in mysql means it tells mysql that one sql statement has been completed till here....so it is used in mysql prompt but not on linux shell or command prompt.

Also if you are executing single sql statement then it is not mandatory as it is mandatory only if you are using multiple sql statements.

You can also check more details at below help link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/entering-queries.html

**Update1:**

Better option is to import from mysql utility as per below-

```
mysql -uroot -p my_db < /my_file_path/file.sql
```

But if you want to do it by source then do as per below-

Connect mysql prompt by below command or you can use any gui tool.

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Now execute below command from mysql prompt-

```
mysql> source /tmp/file.sql
```

Note: mysql should have permission at the path where your file exists normally mysql have rights in /tmp you can check its exact location either in my.cnf or my.ini or by "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'" command.

Special: As this path is used for temporary files by mysql so don't keep important files here.

Comment: this was added in mysql prompt so it should give error

Comment: yes so now we are running the command inside mysql, why don't it demand a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

`source` is a [MySQL client command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), not an SQL command.

Another client command you might be familiar with is `delimiter`. It's use to change the statement terminator so you can use statements like `CREATE PROCEDURE` that contain semicolons. Sometimes I use a double-semicolon because this is definitely something that won't be used in the body of a procedure.

```
mysql> delimiter ;;
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE ... BEGIN ... END ;;
```

Then you can set the delimiter back to the customary `;`

```
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Now think about this: if mysql client commands like `delimiter` needed to have a semicolon terminator, the commands above would be confusing. Would `delimiter ;;` actually set the delimiter to a single `;`, which is then followed by the statement terminator `;`? Would `delimiter ;` set the terminator to a blank?

The solution used by the mysql client is that **builtin commands don't require a statement terminator**.

This applies to all the client built commands, for example:

```
mysql> source file.sql
mysql> pager less
mysql> warnings
mysql> tee outfile.txt
```